# Xcode QR Generator from iPhone to Mac

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, code-generation, qr-code

I have tried to convert 
`https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-QR-Code-Generator/zipball/master` from iPhone app to Mac app.

There are many fails when I set the code over.

How can I convert the app from iPhone to mac?

http://i44.tinypic.com/2s6kfhk.png

http://www.askapps.eu/download/QRGenerator.zip

Comment: That's because the library is C++ - or at least the code in the screenshot certainly is. Your project probably isn't set up to compile C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked briefly at the project in question, it's pretty clear that this is the "Hello, World!" of QR code applications: all it does is convert a fixed string to a QR code and display it in a view. With basic knowledge of Cocoa programming, it wouldn't be difficult to convert the app to run on MacOS X. However, I think a more straightforward strategy would be to just create a new MacOS X app as follows:

- Create a new Cocoa application from the template in Xcode. Add a view controller subclass to manage the image that you'll add to the window. Make sure you provide an outlet to connect the image view.
- Add the QRDraw and libpng folders to your new project.
- Open the main .xib file, which will have an empty window in it. Add an instance of your view controller. Drag an image view into the window, and connect it to your view controller's outlet.
- Following the example in the iOS project, add some code to your view controller class to create a new QR code. Load the resulting image into your image view.

That's as far as I want to break it down. As I said, if you know the basics of Cocoa programming, you should be able to do this without too much trouble. If you haven't written any Cocoa programs before, this would be a great starter project.

Also, make sure that Objective-C++ is enabled in your project. Inerdial's comment above is fundamentally correct -- the error in the linked image seems to be due to the compiler not expecting C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting the following demo iPhone app that uses Core Graphics to generate the actual QR Code image (UIImage). I've not tried it on the Mac, but it may work with little or no modification.

http://www.oscarsanderson.com/2013/08/12/implementing-a-qr-code-generator-on-the-iphone/